# Error: No head is defined for smpeg

Tags: macos, homebrew, simplecv

I am trying to install `SimpleCV`, I am following the instructions here (https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV#mac-os-x-106-and-above).

But when I try to install `smpeg`, using these commands:

```
brew tap homebrew/headonly
brew install --HEAD smpeg
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: No head is defined for smpeg
```

I have tried to wait and run the command again but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** 
I removed `--HEAD` then it worked. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

These instructions are outdated.

`--HEAD` is used to install a formula’s `HEAD`, i.e. the latest commit on its Git/SVN/etc repository. This option has been removed from `smpeg`, hence the error message. Using `brew install smpeg` is now sufficient.

I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/pull/703/files) to fix these.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's exactly what I did and it worked.